# Test failure because of LocalJumpError exception raised (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, exception, testunit

I think I searched for an answer about my problem but I did not see any post that respond to it. So here is yet another question about LocalJumpError...

I'm a relatively newbie in Ruby and I've just decided to follow good pratices and write tests prior to all Ruby stuff I code.

But I got something like a little issue here that I just don't understand. Here is my test :

```rb
class TestFilesInfoLoggerHashCreation < Test::Unit::TestCase
   def setup
      @logger = FilesInfoLogger
   end
   # some other tests
   def test_shall_not_raise_an_exception_if_argument_is_a_string
     assert_nothing_raise @logger.get_log('foo')
   end
end
```

And here is the code that is supposed to verify the specific test above:

```rb
module FilesInfoLogger
  extend self
  def get_log(list)
     hash = Hash.new {||h,k| h[k] = (block_given?)? yield(k):''}
     if list.respond_to? :each 
       list.each {|file| hash[file]}
     else
       ([]<< list).each {|file| hash[file]}
     end
  end
end
```

So when i run `FilesInfoLogger.get_log('foo')` with irb everything seems to work fine, I mean nothing is raised. But when i run the test, it fails returning this :

```
test_shall_not_raise_an_exception_if_argument_is_a_string(TestFilesInfoLoggerHashCreation) [test/files_info_logger_test.rb:43]:
{"foo"=>""}.
 Exception raised:
 <#<LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)>>.
```

I don't understand why according to test unit an exception about no block given is raised especially since I test that condition with `block_given?`. What am I missing?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `assert_nothing_raised` expects a block as an argument. Instead, you are passing it the result of calling `@logger.get_log('foo')`. Try this:

```
assert_nothing_raised do
  @logger.get_log('foo')
end
```